# Where can I find files/db/etc of Memo application?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, data-recovery, default-applications

I'm wondering is it possible (sure it is :)) to find all the memo notes manually and where exactly they are stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android does not have a default memo application, but most android app stores their database in `/data/data/PACKAGE_NAME/databases/`.

Some applications write their data to the sdcard instead, so you might want to check that as well.

Comment: I think you mean `PACKAGE_NAME` ;)

Comment: @onik: true, I was thinking what's the name for the name. Corrected.